# Add formatting to values in a configuration JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file that controls the rendering of an App.
Configuration JSON File has multiple keys and values. And I need to make some text of one of the values to bold.
Is there a way I can do that? I do not have any control over this on the HTML layer.

Below is Code snippet:

```
{
   "name": {
        "short": "Text1
   },
   {
     "description": 
       {
        "short": "Short Text",
        "full": "Long Text and **Text to made bold** and Some more text
    }
}
```

Comment: just use html tag as value, and parsing it when you extract the json

Comment: @RizlanNawfalTamima - You mean passing values as "Long Text and <strong>Text to made bold</strong> and Some more text"

Comment: yeap, i think that is the shortest way, and also there is no "issue" saving the html tag as a value, you can pass string tag anything to that value.

Comment: Tried passing tags in json values but that did not help, the tag gets printed as is on the UI - "<strong> Text to be made bold </strong>" and does not make the text bold
We don not have any control on the UI layer where this json is extracted and rendered.
Is there any way I can make the text bold without using HTML tags

Comment: it seems impossible if you don't have any control on the UI even if u are using double asterisks (**) you should parsing it that the text between the double asterisks must be bold. may I know, what do you use this for?

Comment: We are working on an App which needs to be distributed via Store.
For this we have a configuration file where we have all the necessary information about the App like icons, name, description etc in a configuration file.
We provide this  configuration json file to the publishing Platform which is then used to Publish the App

Comment: So that is configuration (json) file, that required from the store ? appstore or playstore? As far as I know, if they really can provide to bold a text there will be documentation there